# Itō's Lemma neglecting terms

Tags: taylor-expansion, order-theory, stochastic-integrals

In my project I am trying to give a Heuristic proof of Itō's lemma. I show $E[dW_t^2] = dt$

I take $g(x,t)$ to be a twice continuously differentiable function and $dt$ to be infinitesimally small.

Applying Taylors to $g$ gives me,

$dg(W,t) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}dW + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(dW)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial t^2}(dt)^2+ \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial t \partial x}(dt)(dW) + \dots$.

**Question 1**: How can I justify having $dW_t^2 = dt$?

**Question 2**: On what basis do I neglect the other terms? I guess it is because they are of higher order but what does this actually mean?

I end up with $dg(W,t) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}dW + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}dt$

Answer (score 2):

The Itō integral $I\left(t\right)=\int_0^t f\left(s\right) dW\left(s\right)$ has the property that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[I^2\left(t\right)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t f^2\left(s\right)ds\right]
$$
(this is called Itō isometry). Taking $f\left(t\right)=1$ gives you the equation
$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^t dW\left(s\right)\right)^2 \right]=t$ (or $\mathbb{E}\left[dW\left(t\right)\right]=dt$ for short, as you wrote it).

As for the higher order terms, from [Shreve and Karatzas](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387976558), here's what happens to one of the higher order terms that disappears (the rest are similar):

\begin{align*}
 & \lim\left|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}f_{tx}\left(t_{j},W\left(t_{j}\right)\right)\left(t_{j+1}-t_{j}\right)\left(W\left(t_{j+1}\right)-W\left(t_{j}\right)\right)\right|\\
\leq & \lim\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\left|f_{tx}\left(t_{j},W\left(t_{j}\right)\right)\right|\left(t_{j+1}-t_{j}\right)\left|W\left(t_{j+1}\right)-W\left(t_{j}\right)\right|\\
\leq & \lim\max_{0\leq k\leq n-1}\left|W\left(t_{k+1}\right)-W\left(t_{k}\right)\right|\cdot\lim\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\left|f_{tx}\left(t_{j},W\left(t_{j}\right)\right)\right|\left(t_{j+1}-t_{j}\right)\\
= & 0\cdot\int_{0}^{T}\left|f_{tx}\left(t,W\left(t\right)\right)\right|dt=0
\end{align*}

The symbol $\lim$ should be understood as taking the number of intervals $n\rightarrow \infty$ in a fairly "regular" way. The other higher order terms also go to zero with arguments like the above.

**Edit**: Woops, misread your question! You also asked about $dW^2\left(t\right)=dt$. This has to do with quadratic variation, which is not the same thing as the variance of the Itō integral (i.e. $\mathbb{E}\left[I^2\left(t\right)\right]$). The quadratic variation (written $\left[\cdot,\cdot\right]\left(t\right)$) of the Itō integral satisfies

$$
\left[I,I\right]\left(t\right)\equiv\lim\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\left[I\left(t_{j+1}\right)-I\left(t_j\right)\right]^2 = \int_0^t f^2\left(s\right)ds.
$$

Taking $f\left(t\right)=1$ gives you $\left[W,W\right]\left(t\right)=t$ (or $dW^2\left(t\right)=dt$ for short, as you wrote it).

For proofs of the isometry property and the quadratic variation, I would read [Shreve and Karatzas](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387976558). I can also vouch for [Oksendal's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540047581) as being a good read, but I do not remember if he covers the proofs of these claims (he may have skipped over them to focus on other topics).

**Secon Edit:**

Here's the proof for the quadratic variation from Shreve's book. He uses $\Delta$ instead of $f$.

[image: Quadratic variation of Ito integral proof]

Comment: Thanks. I am still a little confused about why $dW_t^2=dt$. Please may you expand and explain what I is in terms of W?

Comment: See above edit for proof of quadratic variation. Also, I already wrote the definition of $I$ at the top of my answer (and it is in terms of $W$).